# Using react_on_rails how can I remount components similar to ReactRailsUJS.mountComponents

Tags: react-rails, react-on-rails

In a react rails project I have converted over from react-rails gem to react_on_rails. Some of the components which are shown in an infinite scroll are re-mounted when they scroll in with `ReactRailsUJS.mountComponents`. How can I remount the components in this way using react_on_rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this issue and have closed the [issue](https://github.com/shakacode/react_on_rails/issues/549)

`ReactOnRails.reactOnRailsPageLoaded()` can be called to remount components on the page manually after async loading.